# How to apply a custom view in Xamarin .axml for Android

Tags: android, xamarin, scrollview

I've been working on implementing the fading action bar and parallax scrolling into my Android UI in my Xamarin app. I needed to extend my ScrollView, and now it's called a NotifyingScrollView. How do i style my .axml now. I can't just write NotifyingScrollView in my axml,

```
namespace NightOut.UiComponents
{
class NotifyingScrollView : ScrollView
{
    public interface IOnScrollChangedListener
    {
        void OnScrollChanged(ScrollView who, int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt);
    }

    private IOnScrollChangedListener mOnScrollChangedListener { get; set; }


    public NotifyingScrollView(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }

    public NotifyingScrollView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
    {

    }

    public NotifyingScrollView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) : base(context, attrs, defStyle)
    {

    }


    [Android.Runtime.Register("onScrollChanged", "(IIII)V", "GetOnScrollChanged_IIIIHandler")]
    protected override void OnScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt)
    {
        base.OnScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
        if (mOnScrollChangedListener != null)
        {
            mOnScrollChangedListener.OnScrollChanged(this, l, t, oldl, oldt);
        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generic example:

```
namespace My.Namespace
{
    class MyCustomView : View
    {
    }
}
```

Is used in following way in .axml

```
<my.namespace.MyCustomView />
```

Or in your specific example:

```
<nightout.uicomponents.NotifyingScrollView />
```

Do mind case, namespace in .axml is lowercase, classname is same case as C# declaration.